# Как сделать форматированный вывод списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Никак не могу понять одну ошибку:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Есть строка, в которую добавляются различные итемы и позже можно вывести итемы (перед последней должно быть `and`):

```
a = []
print("input")

while True:
    name = input()
    if name == "":
        break

    a = a + [name]

print(a[:-1] + " and " + a[-1])
```

Пробовал уже вводить `str` для принта отдельного элемента, выводить через `list(())`, `tuple([])`, но тогда получаю вот такой ответ:

> ['123', '456'] and 789.

Мне нужен результат такой, но без **`[]`** этих скобок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a[:-1] + " and " + a[-1]
```

`а` у вас список, `a[:-1]` - срез списка (т.е. список), " and " - строка, `a[-1]` - последний элемент списка, т.е. тоже строка

ну и как вы список с 2 строками складываете?

если вы вводите несколько строк и хотите чтобы они были превращены в строку, где последний ввод отделен от остальных через " and ", то делать это надо по другому

например в вашем коде надо список превратить в строку

```
' '.join(a[:-1]) + " and " + a[-1]
```

через метод `join` можно объединить все строки в списке в строку через разделитель

в данном примере через пробел

Comment: a[-1] - последний элемент списка, но тоже - строка, да

Comment: @Jack_oS, да, подправил, это я что-то оговорился

Comment: спасибо, в книге не было метода join  и я не знал о нем )) (а так я был напсал str(a[:-1]) но он тоже оказался не верным

Comment: потому что без `join` вам надо было бы по честному пройтись через for по всем элементам списка кроме последнего и делать `text += arr[i]` - тогда бы вы собрали бы строку

Comment: теперь разобрался, спасибо огромное )

Comment: а еще можно так: `print(*a[:-1], 'and', a[-1])`

Comment: @RostikLugovyy [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)